# ScrollView Zooming not Respecting Transform of ImageView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

If I rotate a `UIImageView` that is placed inside a `UIScrollView`, and I zoom in on that UIImageView, the rotation is not respected and the image is reset to `identity`

```
lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
    let view = UIImageView(image: self.image)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    return view
}()

self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi / 2)

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return self.imageView
}
```

The above `viewForZooming` delegate seems to return the UIImageView back to it's identity (in this case portrait).

How can I allow zooming while having it respect the orientation as set?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIScrollView zoom removes transform from UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312724/uiscrollview-zoom-removes-transform-from-uiimageview)

Comment: Thank you for finding that. All my searching did not. Answers the question.

Comment: where did you call the transform of imageview? Why not call it in the viewForZooming ?

Comment: @E.Coms - If you look at the link above it is explained what's happening here. The zoom is doing a transform and so trying to add your own transform in that method causes undesirable results.

Comment: Did you find the solution ? I've exactly the same issue as you